# Push Notification - UIUserNotificationType error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  ...
  UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                              UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                              UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
  UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                       categories:nil];
  [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
  ...
}
```

It's posiibile to make this to work also in xcode 5.1 with iOS 7 ?

Comment: it will not support for xcode 5.1. it will support for xcode 6+

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will not support for xcode 5.1.

for xcode6+ use following code. it will support both for iOS7 and iOS8 Device.

```
//For iOS 8
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)] && [UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
//For iOS 7 & less
else if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)])
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

for register method

```
#pragma mark - For Remote Notification

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{

}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *device_Token = [[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"error : %@",error.localizedDescription);
}
```

When get Notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //notification received
}
```