# Apple Push Notification delegate method not called

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, apple-push-notifications

Was working fine, but with same code neither my success or failed delegate method been called with no error on log either. Testing it on iPad Air(8.0), this issue appear today, is anyone else facing same issue?

Following are my implementation code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    // iOS 8
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please follow this to register remote notification.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504299/push-notification-uiusernotificationtype-error/27504445#27504445)

Comment: Did you change your provisioning profile??

Comment: you have to add `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` when using iOS 8. right now you are using `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` which is for iOS 7.

Comment: Yes I did change the provisioning profile recently, but even I switch back to my old profile I still can't get any device token.

Comment: Suddenly we also facing same issue .. no solution yet .. Its the worst error we are facing now ..

Answer (score 2):

Add these methods to your AppDelegate

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: didRegisterUserNotificationSettings is called, but nothing happen on handleActionWithIdentifier or any other notification related method..

Comment: you also should have added     
    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken;
    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error;

Answer (score 1):

please add below code in didfinishlaund method

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"]) {

        [self application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] didReceiveRemoteNotification:[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"]];
    }
```

Comment: This is almost same as my code, with it I still can't get device token.

Comment: please check your servicer side.. check is pem file is OK ??  this code is perfect am using this code and i got the DEvice token..

Comment: Since I haven't got a device token yet there won't be anything to check on server. I know your code is correct, but still not working for me, so must be something else.